# Signed request - no page data

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm creating a Facebook app to put it in a page tab. I'm doing this after the FB.init() call:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        $.ajax({
            // other parameters omitted
            data: {
                signed_request: response.authResponse.signedRequest
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then I parse the signed request with PHP, but I'm not getting the page info that should come with the signed request. As far as I can tell, the getLoginStatus response comes after the page is loaded within the tab, so I don't know why the signedRequest comes without the page info. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the deal. Facebook POSTs the signed request to the URL you specify in the app details when loading the tab. This is the only time you can grab it to modify your flow. For everything else, there's the JS SDK :)